# MacBook can connect to external monitor AND a Wacom One tablet using Monterey but not using Ventura

Tags: display, ventura, wacom

Under Monterey I could connect my MacBook Pro (2019) to an external monitor (3440 x 1440) *and* to a Wacom One tablet at the same time using two USB-C ports.

After an upgrade to Ventura, I can connect *either* to the Wacom tablet *or* to the external monitor, but not to both. If I add the second external device, the system tries to configure the screens, and tries, and ties,…

Any idea why this happens and how to fix?

Comment: Have you seen their macOS 13 guide? Wacom was always fussy about updates in the past. https://support.wacom.com/hc/en-us/articles/9753655984663

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yes, I saw this guide. It is not the problem that the tablet does not work. It works fine (after udating the Wacom app). But it does not work anymore parallel to the external monitor when both are attached.